# Spring, Hibernate OneToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing

I am using Spring, Hibernate to test some DAO implementations and got a OneToOne assoication problem. When I run the standalone application, it works but when calling the same method in unit test, the OneToOne assoication is not inserted. Here is the undirectional OneToOne relationship mapping:

```
<class name="Person">
<id name="id" column="personId">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property name="checked" column="checked_YN" />
<join table="PersonAddress" 
    optional="true">
    <key column="personId" 
        unique="true"/>
    <many-to-one name="address"
        column="addressId" 
        not-null="true"
        unique="true"/>
</join>
</class>

<class name="Address">
<id name="id" column="addressId">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<ignored other property>
</class>
```

The testDao extends method does:

```
public void createPerson(Person persion) {
     Person p = new Person();
     p.setChecked("Y");
     p.setAddress(testDao.findAddressById(1));        
     session.update(p);
}
```

Unit test class annotation,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/test_context.xml" })
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="my.transaction.manager", defaultRollback=true)
public class MyTestCase {... }
```

Inside unit test, I use spring to get reference of the testDao. when calling the tested method, there is no exception. But when calling p.getAddress(), there is a NullPointerException as the data is not inserted.

```
ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"/test_context.xml"});                          
testDAO = (testDAO)context.getBean("test.dao");
```

When running the application itself, the person checked_yn is updated and a new row with personid and addressid inserted into person_address association table in database, but when running unit test, only checked_yn in person table is updated, and the new row of the association table person_address is not inserted.

I wonder why and what happend. Please help. thanks.

**UPDATE**
This could be a **Hibernate bug (version 3.2.5)**.  when application running itself, the log shows Hibernate (AbstractEntitypersister) do a insert and then update:

```
Insert into Person (....)
Update Person (...)
Insert into Person_address(person_id, address_id) values (?, ?)
Update person_address set address_id = ? where person_id = ?
```

When running unit test, the log shows only update statements:

```
Update Person (...)
Update person_address set address_id = ? where person_id = ?
```

That is why person_address does not exist in unit test, as hibernate does not insert. But how to fix this?

Comment: Please post the exception.

Comment: Is there an exception?, how do you verify that the enities are stored (by the unit test, or do you uses some Database Administration Tool and have a look at the tables)?

Comment: The code matters, and the exception stack trace as well. Show them. We can only guess without this information.

Comment: We still don't know what yoyr code does, and which exception it throws. But frankly, running with a Hibernate version that is more than 6 years, and 50 stable versions old, is asking for trouble. Do you imagine the number of bugs that have been fixed since then?

Comment: A true unit-test should neither interact with a database nor use the spring context.

Comment: I have no choice as this is legacy system, I am not going to upgrade hibernate version. The unit test runs fine without exception when calling session.update(p). Harpun is right, just for convenience at the moment, I am using dbunit and will use in momery database in releases.